# Show newest log entries in file - Linux

Tags: linux, logging

Is there a command in Linux to show only the newest entries in a log file? Ideally something that would clear the log file after each time the file is read.

Comment: Which log file you are refering to?

Comment: `tail` or `tail -f` (for printing new lines automatically) might work for you, although they do not clear the log file (which you can do yourself using `echo -n "" > <name of logfile>` or by `fopen()`ing it with `w` as `mode` parameter).

Comment: @Abrixas2: if you want to empty (clear) a file, just say `> FILENAME`, no need for echo and stuff.

Comment: in this instance tail isn't going to work. Essentially I'm writing a script to read a log file, get the newest entries and take action depending on the contents. Tail has the potential to either re-read previous entries, or skip new entries (if the log file is very active)

Answer (score 5):

There is `tail`, assuming you want to view the last few (`tail -n N` to see the last N, default is 10).  Then `tail -f` will show you the last entries continuously, until you press Ctrl-C to stop it.

None of those tools "clear" the log file as in delete it, but that's a good thing: log files should be appended to, and rarely if ever deleted.

To save space, it is possible to "rotate" (rename and compress) the logs with `logrotate`. See `man logrotate` for further info.

Comment: Normally I would completely agree that log files shouldn't be cleared however, this particular log file is an openvpn log file and a decision has been made to clear the log files in order to assist with protecting the anonymity of users. However I still need to monitor them and take action if required, hence if I can make a script to read the log file, then clear it after each time it's read, that would be ideal.

Comment: Sure, you can make a script to do that using the tools I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

@John Zwinck: Yep the following worked nicely in my script:

```
cat 'logfile'
> 'logfile'
```